# Vulkan - не найдена dll

Tags: windows-10, vulkan

Я хотел запустить "пробник" Vulkan`а из SDK Vulkan.

Сам SDK скачал с: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#windows

Там в папке есть файл bin\vkcube.exe - который просто запускает вращающийся куб. Однако у меня выдает ошибку:

> ...система не обнаружила vulkan-1.dll

Откуда эта dll-ка должна взяться? Это dll-ка берется только от разработчика железа? Процессора или видеокарты?

ОС: Windows 10

Проц: Intel Core i5 9600

Тип граф. процессора: Intel HD Graphics 630 (на сайте интел сказано, что поддерживает Vulkan 1.2)

Дискретной видеокарты - нет.

Windows сообщает, что версия драйвера процессора последняя и обновления не требуется, но файла vulkan-1.dll - то нету.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за ошибка такая?

Comment: Возможно еще надо было  Runtime Installer установить.

Comment: @user7860670, нее, там оказалось, что vkcube.exe ожидает увидеть файл vulkan-1.dll в той же папке в которой находится этот vkcube.exe, а не в какой то системной папке.